# Encryption and decryption in Rails using AES-256-CBC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, routes

I want to secure my rails API using AES-256-CBC algorithm(encryption and decryption).

Sample API url: http://xx.xxx.xxxx.xx/docs.json?meeting_id=X

Encrypted API: http://xx.xxx.xxxx.xx/tsdjhsdfbjfbsdjbfsf===2323232sbsdhd?

The redirection logic is already implemented in routes.rb file. Where should I decrypt the API before sending it to routes file so that the Rails application understands the request format and redirects accordingly with params?

Should this decryption logic be written inside application middleware?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why not force https instead of doing your own encryption?

Comment: One can easily manipulate the API using different params using some sniffer tools with android app.so the params won't be visible anyway.can I use POsT request instead of GET.

Comment: Yes, the HTTP method, or verb, is separate from the protocol. Using POST instead of GET has no bearing on the security, it just makes for prettier URLs and better semantics. Any fool can open the debugger pane on any browser and view the POST params and use myriad tools to submit a POST to your API. When you use httpS, every packet at the http level is encrypted, including the URL, the parameters, etc., so a sniffer would see garbage. But, an incomplete answer to your original question, look at the Rack middleware, maybe starting here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: Even when using HTTPS the parameters are visible if you use tools like Charles, so there are cases where encrypting the parameters may be useful.